# Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare Multiplayer on Xbox One & PS4

Tags: ps4, xbox-one, plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I have a Playstation 4 (PS4) and I have a subscription to Playstation Plus. Is it possible to play Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare multiplayer with my brother on Xbox One, across the Internet, cross-platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no cross-play support for PlayStation and Xbox.